# Lua error attempt to index global nil value csgo

Tags: lua

So im trying to code a lua for a csgo related software but for some reason its giving me this error

```
Exception has occurred: attempt to index a nil value (global 'cheat')
stack traceback:
    c:/Users/trist/Desktop/prediction.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

```lua
    --Hope
local checkhitbox = {0,11,12,13,14}
local username = cheat.GetCheatUserName()
local ideal_yaw
local right_side
local left_side
local dt_charging 
print("" .. username .. " if you have any questions feel free to dm kib1336#1030")
print("" .. username .. " if you have any suggestion or found any bug feel free to join our discord! : https://discord.gg/pJ5WpMV")
local version = "1643"
 --This is the start of the code for the lua
```

Comment: Lua prohibits cheating! :-)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message you are getting is quite clear: the value of the global `cheat` variable is `nil`, but you attempt to index it (to get the value of `GetCheatUserName`). You may need to check where you expect the assignment to `cheat` happen (possibly by loading an external module with `require`).